# Multiple SwingWorker synchronization

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, edt

I have a program that parses XML from web and then shows information in form of JTable. Information can be updated while the program is running.

This update method is called from EDT by a Timer every X seconds or by a user by clicking refresh button.

```
private void updateInfo(int id) {
    SwingWorker<ArrayList<Information>, Void> sw = new SwingWorker<>() {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Information> doInBackground() {
            return loadInfo(id);
        }
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                info = get();
                gui.addInfoToTable(formatInfo(info));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    sw.execute();
}
```

The return of doInBackground() is saved to `info` to allow user see details of specific Information object by clicking specific cell in JTable

Right know I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if I try to stresstest the program with hundreds simultaneous updates.

As far as I understand that is because some of doInBackground() finishes before done(), am I right?

What is the easiest way to make my program threadsafe?

Can accessing info elements while updating cause any problem?

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 10
at java.base/java.util.Vector.elementData(Vector.java:762)
at java.base/java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:500)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:295)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JTable.getCellRenderer(JTable.java:5689)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2184)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintDraggedArea(BasicTableUI.java:2160)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2115)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1883)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:797)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1074)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5255)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1643)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1618)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1556)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1323)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5203)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5013)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:865)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:848)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:848)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:823)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:772)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1890)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Comment: Err, `doInBackground()` **always** finishes before `done()`. That's the whole idea. That's why it's named `done()`. The work in background is done, you may now update the UI with it.

Comment: I meant that while done() is updating UI using the return of its doInBackground() some other doInBackgrounds can finish its job as well(I'm talking about running many SW simultaneously). Or isn't that an issue?

Comment: Is it an issue that data is being loaded in the background? Only the EDT is calling `done()`, so that part is single threaded. Only the dataloading is multithreaded. You haven't given any details of your actual error. I don't see any code that could throw an `AIOOBE` in your question.